# ConTeXt : underbar behavior with subscripts

Tags: formatting, context

With ConTeXt, one generally uses \underbar to underline. \underline also exists, but only for mathematics. I also played a bit with the ideas proposed on [this wiki page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Underlining_With_TextBackgrounds). My tests can be seen on the following MWE.

```
\definetextbackground[myunderlinebackground]
                     [location=text,alternative=1,background=,frame=off]
\def\myunderline#1{
  \starttextbackground[myunderlinebackground]
  #1
  \stoptextbackground
}
\starttext
Hello, this is \underbar{a test}. And now, this is \underbar{a $a_{e}$ test}. 
And this is $\underline{\text{a } a_{e} \text{ test}}$. \\
And this is \myunderline{a $a_{e}$ test}.
\stoptext
```

[image]

However, none of these behaviors suit me. When there is a subscript, I would expect the bar to be broken and restart immediately after (like the underbar 
example, but restarting earlier and not underlying the subscript).
I also notice that \underbar started inside a math environment behaves exactly like \underline.

Is it possible to tune this behavior ?

Comment: Related: http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#jumping

Comment: This is indeed related, but OPmac is a plain TeX solution, I would like something more ConTeXt-like, or at least independant from OPmac. I tried to copy-paste the macro, then the called macros and so on... and finally, even if I input all opmac.tex, I get a "Missing number, treated as zero" error, so it doesn't seem to be a usable solution for a Plain TeX non-user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the ConTeXt-adapted OPMac solution.  Keep in mind that because this is a box it doesn't break across lines.

```
\define[1]\underlinee{%
  \dontleavehmode\vbox to0pt{\vss
    \hrule height.4pt
    \vskip-\baselineskip \kern2.5pt
    \hbox{\strut\rlap{\color[white]{\pdfliteral{2 Tr 1.5 w}#1\pdfliteral{0 Tr 0 w}}}#1}
}}

\starttext
\underlinee{a $a_{e}$ test}
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: @A.Licari This is actually not answer.  It was just too long for a comment.  I'm sure there is a better method using Metafun which I'm not capable of producing.

Comment: Well, at least it is usable, plug-and-play, and it works. I think it is sufficient to be accepted, at least as long no one else submits a "better" answer.